# Перевод из радиан в градусы

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import math as mt


def function():
    l = input("Write name of function(cos, sin, tan, cos_trig, sin_trig or tan_trig): ")
    if l == "cos_trig":
        a = int(input("The length of the opposite leg: "))
        c = int(input("Length of the hypotenuse: "))
        if c == 0:
            exit("Bruh, it doesn't work.")
        cos = a / c
        print(cos)
    elif l == "sin_trig":
        b = int(input("The length of the adjacent leg: "))
        c = int(input("Length of the hypotenuse: "))
        if c == 0:
            exit("Bruh, it doesn't work.")
        sin = b / c
        print(sin)
    elif l == "tan_trig":
        a = int(input("The length of the opposite leg: "))
        b = int(input("The length of the adjacent leg: "))
        if b == 0:
            exit("Bruh, it doesn't work")
        tan = a / b
        print(tan)
    elif l == "cos":
        x = mt.degrees(int(input("Angle: ")))
        print(round(mt.cos(mt.degrees((x))),2))
    elif l == "sin":
        x = int(input("Radian: "))
        print(mt.sin((x)))
    elif l == "tan":
        x = int(input("Radian: "))
        print(mt.tan(x))
    else:
        print("Unknown function")


function()
```

В строках нужно перевести все из радианы в градусы, но у меня почему не получается, даже при использовании math.degrees(x)

```
    elif l == "cos":
        x = mt.degrees(int(input("Angle: ")))
        print(round(mt.cos(mt.degrees((x))),2))
    elif l == "sin":
        x = int(input("Radian: "))
        print(mt.sin((x)))
    elif l == "tan":
        x = int(input("Radian: "))
        print(mt.tan((x)))
```

Вот что у меня получается, хотя должно получатся 1.

```
Write name of function(cos, sin, tan, cos_trig, sin_trig or tan_trig): cos
Angle: 90
-0.08
```

Comment: "_но у меня почему не получается, даже при использовании math.degrees(x)_" - какие будут ваши доказательства? Тут не видно даже попыток перевести радианы в градусы. Хотя ничего нет проще.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код** для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: Вы считываете радианы и кастуете к инту. У вас ответы будут 0, 57, 114 градусов и т.д. Какой там у вас в питоне тип с плавающей точкой?

Comment: @Kromster, это достаточно минимальный код, чтобы в нем можно было разобраться. Проблема также описана. Если вопрос закроют, я первым проголосую за переоткрытие.

Comment: @insolor, специально подчеркнул, что ТС должен минимизировать свой код, и тогда, вероятно даже сам увидит в нем ошибку и исправит. Для базы знаний, код тоже должен быть минимален.

Comment: @Kromster, есть конкретный человек с конкретными проблемами, а есть абстрактное "светлое будущее" в виде "базы знаний". Если человек с опытом программирования, то у него может быть одна большая проблема, которую он не может решить, и он задает вопрос с минимальным кодом. Если человек без опыта, то у него весь код заполнен мелкими проблемами. При этом код умещается на один экран, и все проблемы можно решить в рамках одного ответа. Я считаю, что в этом случае требовать минимизации кода и разбиения вопроса на несколько частей - это издевательство.

Comment: Опять же ИМХО: минимизация нужна не для "буквы закона" (правил сайта) или "базы знаний", а для того, чтобы в коде можно было разобраться, и найти конкретную проблему. Если проблема находится без минимизации при беглом взгляде на код - то и минимизировать нечего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вводите 90, тут же переводите 90 в градусы (т.е. получается, что 90 - это радианы):

```
x = mt.degrees(int(input("Angle: ")))
```

А в следующей строчке переводите `х` опять в градусы. Что по-вашему должно получиться?

Если вы вводите угол в градусах, то

```
x = int(input("Angle: "))
print(round(mt.cos(mt.radians(x)), 2))
```

Если в радианах, то

```
x = int(input("Angle: "))
print(round(mt.cos(x), 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Функция `degrees` служит для перевода **радианов** в **градусы**, а вам нужно наоборот. Используйте функцию `radians` вместо `degrees`.
2. Не нужно несколько раз переводить, это ни к чему хорошему не приведет. Например, для перевода из градусов в радианы используется такая формула: `rad = deg * pi  / 180`, т.е.  `deg / 57.29577951308232`. Если это сделать два раза, то получится `r = deg * pi * pi / 180 / 180` , т.е. `x = deg * pi ** 2 / 32400`, что примерно равно `deg / 3282.806350011744` - а это явно не то что нужно.
   Двойные скобки `((x))` тоже не нужны, но правда они и не вредят.
3. Для вывода с округлением до 2 знаков после запятой лучше использовать `format`, а не `round` (`round` округлит, но при выводе все равно может получиться `0.1200000001`).
4. Для ввода радиан (да и для градусов тоже) при преобразовании из строки в число используйте `float` вместо `int` (иначе получите ошибку при вводе дробных значений).

Кусок кода с исправлениями:

```
elif l == "cos":
    x = mt.radians(float(input("Angle: ")))
    print('{.2f}'.format(mt.cos(x)))
elif l == "sin":
    x = float(input("Radian: "))
    print('{.2f}'.format(mt.sin(x)))
```